# Legend in Matlab Plotting

Tags: matlab, plot

I have some issues with the legends. I am trying to plot using this code and the code is this:

```
function PlotNormalPlot(z,i)
hold on
plotTypes = {'b', 'm', 'c'};
TrancheRange = {'100','1000','10000'};
h = normplot(z);
set(h,'color',plotTypes{i})
xlabel('Estimate')
ylabel('Probability')
legendInfo{i} = TrancheRange{i};
legend(legendInfo);
end
```

It is giving me this error:

```
Error using legend>process_inputs (line 552)
Cell array argument must be a cell array of strings.
```

Not sure why this error is there? Need some guidance.

EDIT:

When i tried this:

```
function PlotNormalPlot(z,i)
hold on
plotTypes = {'b', 'm', 'c'};
TrancheRange = {'100','1000','10000'};
h = normplot(z);
set(h,'color',plotTypes{i})
xlabel('Estimate')
ylabel('Probability')
%legendInfo = TrancheRange{i};
legend(TrancheRange);
end
```

The legend came out well but the color doesn't get attached to the legend. Not sure why.

Looks like this now:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `legendInfo=TrancheRange{i}`, so `legendInfo` is a single string.

`legendInfo{i}` will create a cell array, and, for `i=2` as an example, would give you `legendInfo={[] '2'}` where the first element of `legendInfo` is an empty array.

---

I think this could answer your second question. It saves the legend information with the plot handle:

```
h = normplot(z);
set(h,'color',plotTypes{i},'DisplayName',TrancheRange{i})
legend(h,'show')
```

Comment: legendInfo=TrancheRange{i}, then only the last one is appearing, the rest legends are not appearing.

Comment: what rest ? legendInfo appears only one time in your function.